# Hadoop 2.2 Add new Datanode to an existing hadoop installation

Tags: hadoop

I first installed hadoop 2.2 on my machine (called Abhishek-PC) and everything worked fine. I am able to run the entire system successfully. (both namenode and datanode).

Now I created 1 VM hdclient1 and I want to add this VM as a data node.

Here are the steps which I have followed

1. I setup SSH successfully and I can ssh into hdclient1 without a password and I can login from hdclient1 into my main machine without a password.
2. I setup hadoop 2.2 on this VM and I modified the configuration files as per many tutorials on the web. Here are my configuration files

Name Node configuration

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0dV2NMSGYPXdEM1WmRqVG5uYlU/edit?usp=sharing

Data Node configuration

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0dV2NMSGYPXRnh3YUo1X2Frams/edit?usp=sharing

1. Now when I start start-dfs.sh on my first machine, I can see that DataNode starts successfully on hdclient1. Here is a screenshot from my hadoop console.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0dV2NMSGYPXOEJ3UV9SV1d5bjQ/edit?usp=sharing

As you can see both the machines appear in my cluster (main main and data node).

Although both are called "localhost" for some strange reason.

1. I can see that the logs are being created on hdclient1in those logs there are no exceptions.

here are the logs from the name node

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0dV2NMSGYPXM0dZTWVRUWlGaDg/edit?usp=sharing

Here are the logs from the data node

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0dV2NMSGYPXNV9wVmZEcUtKVXc/edit?usp=sharing

1. I can login to the namenode UI successfully `http://Abhishek-PC:50070`

but here the UI in the live nodes it says only 1 live node and there is no mention of hdclient1.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0dV2NMSGYPXZmMwM09YQlI4RzQ/edit?usp=sharing

1. I can create a directory in hdfs successfully `hadoop fs -mkdir /small`
2. From the datanode I can see that this directory has been created by using this command `hadoop fs -ls /`
3. Now when I try to add a file to my HDFS and I say

hadoop fs -copyFromLocal ~/Downloads/book/war_and_peace.txt /small

i get an error message

> abhishek@Abhishek-PC:~$ hadoop fs -copyFromLocal
>   ~/Downloads/book/war_and_peace.txt /small 14/01/04 20:07:41 WARN
>   util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your
>   platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable 14/01/04
>   20:07:41 WARN hdfs.DFSClient: DataStreamer Exception
>   org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(java.io.IOException): File
>   /small/war_and_peace.txt.*COPYING* could only be replicated to 0 nodes
>   instead of minReplication (=1).  There are 1 datanode(s) running and
>   no node(s) are excluded in this operation.    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager.chooseTarget(BlockManager.java:1384)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:2477)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.addBlock(NameNodeRpcServer.java:555)

So my question is What am I doing wrong here? Why do I get this exception when I try to copy the file into HDFS?

Comment: What does 'jps' show on each machine/VM? Can you ping all boxes from all boxes? What's the IP of the master/namenode on each box? Helps to have the same etc/hosts on each machine. We have a 3-node cluster functioning for a while and can provide settings tomorrow.

Comment: Also, please try starting services one by one, 'hadoop-daemon start namenode', hadoop-daemons.sh start datanode, 'yarn-daemon.sh start resourcemanager' and 'yarn-daemon.sh start nodemanager' and running 'jps' after each to check the status.

Comment: On first machine (namenode+datanode) jps results in `20731 SecondaryNameNode
21198 NodeManager
20389 NameNode
21057 ResourceManager
21302 Jps
20525 DataNode
` on hdclient1 and hdclient2 jps results in `4825 DataNode
4960 NodeManager
5115 Jps`. Yes. I can ping all nodes from all places. and I can also do ssh from all nodes to all other nodes.

Comment: Does your namenode machine have a firewall preventing the other datanodes from connecting to it? Do your data node logs from the newly added VMs show successful connection to the name node?

Comment: There is no firewall. on my main machine if I do a `hadoop fs -mkdir /foo` and then on my VMs (hdclient1, hdclient2) I do a `hadoop fs -ls /` I can see that foo being listed. so ofcourse, not only the datanode is being started there.... hadoop is working across machines. but now if I do a `hadoop dfsadmin -printTopology` it says there is only 1 data node and not 3 data node.

Comment: Your setup seems to be fine. Have you tried running a job? What's your dfs-replication value in hdfs-site.xml?

Comment: I haven't tried running a job after adding nodes because I wanted all the data nodes to do processing. here is my hdfs-site.xml `<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.replication</name>
        <value>2</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.permissions</name>
        <value>false</value> 
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
        <value>file:/mydata/dfs/namenode</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
        <value>file:/mydata/dfs/datanode</value>
    </property>
</configuration>`

Comment: It looks fine. I assume you've created the datanode and tmp folders on every machine and namenode was formatted. What does "http://localhost:8088/cluster/nodes" show?

Comment: humm... I see 2 nodes... but both of them say "localhost"

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0dV2NMSGYPXOEJ3UV9SV1d5bjQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: but if I try to add a file to my hdfs it says `org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(java.io.IOException): File /small/war_and_peace.txt._COPYING_ could only be replicated to 0 nodes instead of minReplication (=1).  There are 1 datanode(s) running and no node(s) are excluded in this operation.
 at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager.chooseTarget(BlockManager.java:1384)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:2477)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.addBlock(NameNodeRpcServer.java:555)
 at org`

Comment: it's really hard to debug without being able to read the logs or look at your setup. I'd recommend using the guide below and restart. Please make sure /etc/hosts is correct.

Comment: I have updated the problem statement above to include all logs and configuration files. 

I have also started a bounty ... just to be thankful for your efforts...

Answer (score 0):

We have a 3-node cluster (all physical boxes) that's been working great for a couple of months. [This](http://hortonworks.com/wp-content/uploads/downloads/2013/06/Apache.Hadoop.YARN_.Sample.pdf) article helped me the most to setup.

Comment: I double checked my setup against this article. But could not make my setup work.